# Express не виден запрос

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Всем привет практикую express.

Пишу rest api.
Пытаюсь вывести ключ.

Но я не понимаю почему он не видит `apiKey` отосланный.
пытаюсь вообще понять суть работы и через `req.body.apiKey undefined`.

Поскажите пожалуйста, как мне просто сделать проверку.
Верный ключ или нет. Потому что он не видит что я отсылаю.
Вижу только через

```
req.params ( { apiKey: 'apiKey=258cf54c-a09c-4bbb-9903-32e7954e1a5f' } )
```

Запрос делаю так:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/apiKey=258cf54c-a09c-4bbb-9903-32e7954e1a5f
```

роутер

```
router.get('/api/v1/:apiKey', count)
```

контроллер

```
const dbh = require("../middleware/connect");

const count = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log(req.body.apiKey);
    dbh.query("SELECT * FROM `keyus` WHERE `ukey` = '" + req.body.apiKey + "'", (err,rows,fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(rows)
        }
        }
    )
}
module.exports = { count }
```

Comment: Может фигню скажу, но попробуйте получить ключ вот так
const { apiKey } = req.params;

Comment: к сожалению ничего не выводится.

Comment: `req.body` есть когда отсылают допустим `post` запрос. В вашем случае вы пытаетесь получить параметр, и для этого в вашем запросе не нужно писать `apiKey=...`. Значение для `:apiKey` будет хранится в объекте `req.params`, а именно `req.params.apiKey`.

Comment: Согласен с комментатором выше, добавлю то, что вам необходимо скорее всего переходить по следующему URL http://localhost:3000/api/v1/258cf54c-a09c-4bbb-9903-32e7954e1a5f   . Да, то есть без apiKey=

Comment: @HTOHOT, хорошо. я понял. я не могу понять почему я получаю пустой массив по запросу?

Comment: А вы в sql вставили req.params.apiKey?

Comment: @HTOHOT, да вот только что вставил. Сглупил. А как мне сделать с филдами апи?
по типу как я и хотел apikey=key.Я видимо не совсем правильно сделал

Comment: Вам нужно убрать из вашего эндпоинта "/ :apiKey" (из строки ```router.get('/api/v1/:apiKey', count)``` )
и получать это можно с помощью req.query (ссылка должна иметь вид http://localhost:3000/api/v1?apiKey=258cf54c-a09c-4bbb-9903-32e7954e1a5f)
Вот вам для ознакомления https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-query-property 
И вот про query параметры подробнее https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/http_protocol/lessons/query_string/theory_unit